# Transformations in LMI constraints

Tags: matrices, convex-optimization, semidefinite-programming, linear-matrix-inequality, schur-complement

Suppose that $T$ is a symmetric and invertible matrix. The following must be true

\begin{equation}\label{eq:SDP}\left[\begin{array}{cc}
X & A \\
A^{\top} & B
\end{array}\right] \succeq 0 \Leftrightarrow\left[\begin{array}{cc}
X & A T \\
T^{\top} A^{\top} & T B T^{\top}
\end{array}\right] \succeq 0\end{equation}

I have an SDP constraint of the form on the left. Empirically, I have observed that some matrices $T$ lead to faster convergence in the semi-definite program then the trivial case when $T = I$, where $I$ is an identity matrix.

My question is: Is it possible to systematically determine a matrix $T$ which will lead to faster convergence of the SDP ?

I am guessing that pre and post multiplying the matrix changes its condition number. However, I can't see how that relates to faster convergence of SDP.

\begin{equation}\left[\begin{array}{cc}
I & 0 \\
0 & T
\end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{ll}
X & A \\
A^{\top} & B
\end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{ll}
I & 0 \\
0 & T
\end{array}\right]\end{equation}

Comment: What method are you using to solve your SDP?  Are your optimal $X$ matrices singular?

Comment: I just let MOSEK solve the SDP. Also, X is symmeretric psd and it does not turn out to be singular. Could you please elaborate on how to choose a T for conditioning

Comment: Mosek uses the self dual embedding method in a primal-dual embedding method to solve the problem.  This will probably be important.

Comment: Are there any additional linear constraints in your problem?  What are the condition numbers of $[X A; A^{T} B]$ and $[X AT; T^{T}A^{T} TBT^{T}]$?